# Trying to resize disk partitions in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: partitioning, disk, resize

Running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS on HP Laptop and been trying to add all the current 180GB Free Space to my Filesystem space. The current disk partition set up [System Partition 1 - 25GB][Free Space - 180GB][Filesystem Part.5 - 50GB Ext 4][Free Space -1Gb].

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

One cannot alter the layout of a disk if any of the disk's partitions is `mount`ed.

You will have to boot from your install medium in "Try Ubuntu" mode, or from a USB stick with a system on it.

It looks like you are using an extended partition (an old trick to fool old DOS systems).

Run `gparted`, shrink the extended partition to move the free space from the extended partition to real free space and expand your "Part 5". Or, if you  want  to expand your "System partition", omit the "shrink the extended partition" step.

Comment: Thanks got it worked out, gave up on it 2 years ago just been using an external drive to compensate for the 50GB limit.